# prove there's another subsequental limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$a_n$ a sequence such that:
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} :|{a_{n + 1}} - {a_n}| < 1$
$\{ 0,2\} \subseteq P({a_n})  $

Prove there's another subsequental limit, $L \ne 0,2$

I'll be glad for help here

Comment: What does the notation $P( a_n)$ mean?

Comment: $P(a_n)$ is the set of all the subsequental limits of $a_n$

Comment: I fixed the direction. sorry about that..

Comment: Between any two indices $m,n$ such that $a_m$ is close to $0$, and $a_n$ close to $2$, there must be an index $k$ such that $a_k \in \;?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B=(\infty, \frac{1}{2})$, $M=[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}]$ and $T=(\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$.

Let $I_B = \{ n | a_n \in B\}$ and similarly for $I_M,I_T$. By assumption, both $I_B, I_T$ are infinite.

I claim that $ I_M$ is infinite as well. Take some $N$. Then there is some $n_1,n_2 \ge N$ such that $n_1 \in B$, $n_2 \in T$. Let $k > n_1$ be the first index greater than $n_1$ such that $a_k \in T$. Since $a_k \in T$ and $|a_{k-1}-a_k| < 1$, we must have $a_{k-1} \in M$. Since this is true for arbitrary $N$, we have that $I_M$ is infinite.

Since $M$ is compact, we must have a convergent subsequence whose limit lies in $M$.